# React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child with <Link > component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am learning react by myself. In my rendering loop I tried to add the  element inside so that I can make the  hyperlink for each data. But I got this issue:React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child. Could someone know why it happened? Here is part of my code.Hope it make easier to understand my question. I skipped some parts of my coding as it seems the issue happened in the render part.

app.js

```
render() {
return (
  <Router className="App">
    <div>
      <nav className="navbar navbar-default">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <Link to="/coding-fun">Coding Fun</Link>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <Switch>
        // import condingFun.js file as Coding  
        <Route exact path="/coding-fun" component={Coding} />
        <Route path="/coding-fun/:title" component={singleArticle} />

      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Router>
);
```

}
}

codingFun.js
ps: posts is json data which I didn't add here as too many data.

```
 class Coding extends Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div className="nav-text">
            <h1>Coding fun page</h1>
            // posts is data from api, and it renders listPage.js as 
              ListPage 
            <ListPage items={posts} />
         </div>
       );
  }
}

 export default Coding;
```

listPage.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Link } from "react-router-dom";

class Listing extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = { data: this.props.items };
    }

   render() {
     return (
  <table>
    <tbody>
      // loop "post" data from parent component (items) codingFun.js  
      {this.state.data.map(post => (
        <tr key={post.id}>
          <td>
            <Link to={"coding-fun/" + post.title}>{post.title}</Link>
          </td>
          <td>{post.content}</td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
  </table>
  );
}
```

}

If I just add
    `<Link to={"coding-fun/" + post.title}>{post.title}</Link>`
this line, it got "React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child." issue. If I only add {post.title} in the  tag, there is no any issue. So I tried to make the title as link in each row. But I don't know how to make it.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property `to` does not exist in `BrowserRouter`. You are also confusing yourself a little bit there by aliasing `BrowserRouter` with `Link` because there exists an actual component in react-router called `Link`. And this is how you use it:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

<Link to={"coding-fun/" + post.title}>{post.title}</Link>
```

Comment: I had the same problem, I'd copied `import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from "react-router-dom"` from somewhere then removed the `as Router` as I didn't need it. Seems obvious now, should have fixed this myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it's because you are doing the import wrong. The import statement should be `import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'`

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing between `Router`, `Link` and `Route`. So basically,

- `Router` is used to wrap your entire app, to make it **fullstack-alike**, which means the URL in address bar can be changed and the specific view is rendered respectively
- `Link` is used the same way as `<a>` tag, which means that it will take you to that URL when clicked
- `Route`, on the other hand, is used to decide what should be rendered under a specific link. This is what you should use to pass children component

In your case, you should change the `import` statement to:

`import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'`

Hope this help solve your problem :)